# Google Analytics GA4 User Problems

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

We want to pull data with google analytics ( GA4 ) api connection in our website. We have fulfilled all the conditions in the Google Analytics Api Documents. Although we have given the necessary Google analytics permissions, we receive a warning that user permissions are not valid on localhost. When we provide the necessary downloads and connections to our web server, thinking that it gives an error because it works through the Local Server, we get an HTTP ERROR 500 error on the page.

We made the necessary JSON file and library integrations over the compesor, but the same error continues. Despite all our attempts, we could not establish a connection.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> user does not have sufficient permission for this profile

Is one of the more common error messages.   When you run your code you are connecting to a Google Analytics account.  The user you are using to connect to this measurement id must have permissions to access that data.  The error message is telling you that the user does not.

The solution is to either authencation your code with a user who has access, or grant that user access.